# input strings in c and how to store the string into variable

Tags: c, string, input, c-strings

this is a really basic question but I couldn't find anything about this through google. 
So let's say a main functions gets passed some input strings.  I am trying

```
main(argc, const char* argv[]) {
   char* test = argv[1]; // works but gives error if not at beginning of function

   char* test2;
   test2 = argv[2]; // error: invalid casting from const type

   char* test3;
   strcpy(test3, argv[3]); // run-time failure

   char test4[10];
   strcpy(test4, argv[4]); // works but what if the input string's length cannot be guaranteed
}
```

This is so basic... yet I am so clueless.

Comment: Always state *what* error you get. Also, your `main` declaration is not entirely complete. What happens when you remove the `const`?

Comment: By the way, the reason for the `run-time failure` should be obvious: you are copying data into 'nowhere' (actually *anywhere*).

Comment: @Martin James  Inputs are just arbitrary strings.

Comment: How is it "obvious" that *pseudocode* gives you compile and/or run-time errors?

Comment: Because those lines with the same format and different variable names give me errors in my program...........   Was I supposed to submit my 350 line program just for a few lines in question?  I also had to show the different things I was trying.  I'm asking a question about a concept involving strings not a 'review my code' question.  I guess a better way to ask this question would have been 'why does the first and last way work (but are bad form), while the other 2 ways don't'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c a string is a pointer to some block of memory each byte of which contains a character. Say I have the following code:

`char * helloString = "hello"`

Once this has run *all* that is stored in helloString is the position in memory of the character 'h'. The next 5 positions in memory contain bytes representing 'e', 'l', l', 'o' and '\0' the last being a special character called NULL which tells c where the end of the string is.

In order to copy a string at runtime to have to first allocate some memory to put the characters then copy them across to the new memory. The reason that strcpy failed in your example is that there was no memory allocated for your program to copy the characters into. You need to do something like this:

```
int len = strlen(argv[1]);
char test[len]; //or char * test = malloc(len);
strcpy(argv[1], test);
```

Note however that this code will do *very* bad things (seg fault if you're lucky) if argv[1] doesn't have a '\0' at the end!

Comment: Thanks!  My compiler doesn't let me initialize a dynamically sized array, I had to use malloc.  But this is how I solved my problem.  thanks!

Comment: @jnel899 If you used malloc make sure you free() the memory after you've finished with it! [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is a good tool to check you're not leaking any memory in your program. 

Run time length arrays have been in the c standard for a while. If possible I suggest you upgrade your compiler to one which supports c99 (an up to date gcc for example).

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned it is pseudo code,  I cannot help with fixing your code. 
You must allocate memory for your test variables or initialize them with length that fits your input.

Comment: ok... But how would I get an input string into a declared variable? Char* test = (char*) malloc (strlen(argv[1])); test = argv[1]; gives the same invalid casting error.  I can't figure out how to format this comment, sorry.

Comment: You do it in either one of the ways you used, but after allocating memory, there will be actually where to put the string...

Comment: Ok, I got it to work finally.  Char* test = (char*) malloc (strlen(argv[1])); strcpy(test, argv[1]); works fine.  Sorry I am pretty unfamiliar with C.  Thanks for the help.